# Google App engine - Search API 10GB per-index limit

Tags: google-app-engine

In the app engine release notes 1.9.0 is stated:

"The size limit on the Search API is now computed and enforced on a per-index basis, rather than for the app as a whole. The per-index limit is now 10GB. There is no fixed limit on the number of indexes, or on the total amount of Search API storage an application may use."

The Search API is now in experimental state, but I would like to know if the 10GB per-index limit will be removed when the Search API will be out of experimental (or at least, will be replaced with a much larger one).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [Search API quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Search_API_quotas), the current quota is still **10 GB** per index.  There are no public plans to increase this quota at the time of this writing.

Should this quota increase be desired, feel free to file a new feature request on the [App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) detailing a thorough business case.  You may also want to consider supporting this existing and related issue: [Issue 10667: Search API multiple index search](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10667).

Comment: Hi Nicholas, we have a Silver subscription to app engine and I would like to know what steps in detail, should (can) i take to request a limit increase from Google App Engine support?